# jquery delay function

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

My delay function is not working in my **jquery** rotate function. I am not sure why.

Basically, my code will make my div turn an angle and it will stop at a certain angle. This works at the moment. However i added a delay so it it will work after 3 or 4 seconds.

However its not doing it.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $elie = $("#super");
    rotate(1);

    function rotate(degree) {
        $elie.css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
        });
        console.log(degree);
        if (degree < 55) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                rotate(++degree)
            }, 10)
            delay: 4000;
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: You know that you don't need all that browser-specific attributes? just 'transform' if you use an updated jQuery library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delay the rotation just make a 'setTimeout' around the delay function:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $elie = $("#super");
    setTimeout(function() {
        rotate(1);
    }, 4000)

    function rotate(degree) {
        $elie.css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
        });
        console.log(degree);
        if (degree < 55) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                rotate(++degree)
            }, 10)
        }
    };
});​
```

(also as mentioned removed the dalay: 4000, which don't has the effect you want!)

Fiddler example: http://jsfiddle.net/49VEe/

edit2:

You can use [HTML5 `transition`](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/) to get the rotation effect instead of your recursive function (sample without delay:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $elie = $("#super");
        rotate(55);

    function rotate(degree) {
        $elie.css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transition': 'all 1s ease-in-out',
            '-moz-transition': 'all 1s ease-in-out',
            '-o-transition': 'all 1s ease-in-out',
            transition: 'all 1s ease-in-out'
        });
    };
});​
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/mZzjP/

Answer (score 2):

If you want the rotation to start after a few seconds, wrap the initial `rotate(1);` in a `setTimeout` like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { rotate(1); }, 3000); // 3 seconds
```

You should also remove `delay: 4000;` as that will only cause an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (degree < 55) {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        rotate(++degree)
    }, 10);
    delay: 4000; // remove this
}
```

into

```
if (degree < 55) { 
    timer = setTimeout(function () { rotate(++degree) }, 10);
}
```

You also need an initial setTimout like so

```
setTimeout( rotate(1), 4000 );
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsY26/1/)